# ¿Cómo actualizar solo la vista con AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Cuando creo un registro debo recargar solamente la vista, actualmente recargo toda la página.

```
$scope.CrearUsuario = function(item)
    {
        $scope.item = item;
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "../ws/usuarios",      
            data: {
                nombre1:        item.nombre1,
                nombre2:        item.nombre2,
                apellido1:      item.apellido1,
                apellido2:      item.apellido2,
                usuario:        item.usuario,
                password:       item.password,
                idtipousuario:  item.idtipousuario
            }
        }).then(function mySucces(response)
        {   
            var opts = {
                "closeButton": true,
                "debug": false,
                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
                "onclick": null,
                "showDuration": "100",
                "hideDuration": "1000",
                "timeOut": "3000",
                "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                "showEasing": "swing",
                "hideEasing": "linear",
                "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
            };              
            toastr.success("Usuario creado correctamente.", "Exito !", opts);
            $rootScope.currentModal.close();
            window.location.reload();
        }, function myError(response){
            console.log("Error");
        });
    }
```

De esta forma, hago que recargue la página `window.location.reload();` Como puedo recargar únicamente en la vista que estoy trabajando, la verdad no tengo mayor idea en esto.

Comment: has probado [`$scope.$apply();`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)?

Comment: no tengo idea de como aplicarlo.

Comment: Tu vista entiendo que consiste en un listado de objetos o similar, ¿no?.

Comment: Si es correcto, en esa vista muestro una tabla de  registros de usuarios.

Comment: Mira a ver si la respuesta que te he dado te vale, yo actualmente lo hago así.

Comment: con solo asignar el elemento del arreglo te actualizara la vista sin problema, puede que algunas veces tengas errores y debes realizar el $apply que dice lois6b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que dices que tienes en la vista es una lista de objetos para pintarlos por pantalla habrás usado un array.

Yo actualmente en mi aplicación lo que hago es volver a llamar al servicio y pintar los datos actualizados.

Para ello es necesario que primero establezcas la longitud del array en el que almacenas la respuesta a 0. Y después introduzcas dichos resultados de nuevo en él.

```
toastr.success("Usuario creado correctamente.", "Exito !", opts);
        $rootScope.currentModal.close();
        this.reloadView();
    }, function myError(response){


    reloadView(): void{
         this.arrayVista.length = 0;
         this.recuperarUsuarios();
     }
```

Y dentro de la función `recuperarUsuarios()` imagino que ya tendrás algo similar a

`this.arrayVista = res`

Yo es la única forma que he encontrado de conseguir lo que tu pides. De momento son pocos registros los que recupero por lo que la carga y el consumo de recursos no es gran cosa. No obstante cuando esto sea un problema simplemente con preparar el back para que permita paginación lo tendrías solventado.